# How to search/filter from a paged list data source in Android

Tags: android, android-room, pagedlist

**Issue**

I'm setting up data using a PagedList. How do I filter/search through the list while using Room.

I've tried filtering the list on the DataSource class while making a request but want to make it filter from the initial results loaded.

```
itemViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity).get(ItemViewModel.class);

 itemViewModel.itemPagedList.observe(this, new Observer<PagedList<Item>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable PagedList<Item> items) {
                itemsAdapter.submitList(items);

            }
        });
```

I expect to submit a filtered paged list on search.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Get your filtered data from your data source for example

```
    @WorkerThread
    @Query("SELECT * from chats where isGroup = :isGroup AND chatName LIKE :query")
    fun search(query: String, isGroup: Int = 0): DataSource.Factory<Int, Chat>
```

Step 2: Check if result not null remove old observer and  observe new result (pass result to replaceSubscription function)

Step 3: End search remove observer again from filtered data and re-observe old data
    (pass null to replaceSubscription function)

```
      fun search(query: String?) {
            if (query.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                return
            }
            Log.d(ChatsFragment::class.java.simpleName, "search")
            Log.d(ChatsFragment::class.java.simpleName, "search($query: String?)")
            viewModel.search(query = "$query%", result = object : 
            ChatFragmentViewModel.SearchResult {
                override fun result(chats: LiveData<PagedList<Chat>>?) {
                    if (chats != null) {
                        isInSearchMode = true
                        replaceSubscription(chats)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

replaceSubscription function

```
fun replaceSubscription(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, data:LiveData<PagedList<Chat>>? = null) {
    chats.removeObservers(lifecycleOwner)
    chats = data ?: result.pagedList
}
```

observe function

```
 private fun observeChats() {
        Log.d(ChatsFragment::class.java.simpleName, "observeChats")
        viewModel.chats.observe(this, Observer<PagedList<Chat>> { data ->
            getNumberOfUnreadMessagesAtAll(data.snapshot())
            chatsAdapter.submitList(data)
        })

        // start observing for networkState
        viewModel.networkState.observe(this, Observer {
            chatsAdapter.setNetworkState(it)
        })
    }
```

Note: i got this idea from a post here but i don't remember where and who